# Hibernate 6 - Enum mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I am migrating from hibernate 5 to 6 and I have a lot of problems with Enums.

There is no example on how to use enum mapping with postgres and hibernate 6. As @TypeDef is no more available I don't know how I can map my enum type to my database column.

I have the following enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   ENTRY1,
   ENTRY2,
}
```

Before the migration to hibernate 6 my working entity was like this:

```
@TypeDef(name="pgsql_enum", typeClass= com.mycompany.PostgreSQLEnumType)
public class MyEntity
{
   @Id
   private int id;

    @Type(type="pgsql_enum")
    private MyEnum enum;

    //...
}



public class PostgreSQLEnumType<T extends Enum<T>> extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType<T>
{
    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, T value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
    {
        st.setObject(index, value != null ? ((Enum) value).name() : null, Types.OTHER;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve to do the same with hibernate 6.2 ?
(My enums are used in named queries so the solution must work with named queries)

Answer (score 2):

I had to migrate recently as well. I think it's quite simpler now. Assuming you've settled the right dependencies (Please read [here](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/#installation-guide)) to allow you migrate to Hibernate 6, here's the only change I had to make:

```
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

// the usual JPA annotations
public class MyEntity
{
   @Id
   private int id;

    @Column(name = "column_name")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
    private MyEnum enum;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeDef is replaced by TypeRegistration annotation. This is applicable to UserTypes, for BasicTypes you will need to register using TypeContributors.